# Generalized Triangle Inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, real-numbers, triangle-inequality

Can we generalize the triangle inequality for general $p >0?$

More precisely,
for what values of $p >0,$ the triangle inequality
$$|x+y|^p \leq |x|^p+|y|^p$$ holds for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$

If not do we have analogue of triangle inequality in some sense for $p>0?$

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space

Comment: The name of the inequality you are searching for is called Minkowski's inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have a strict inequality for $0 < p < 1$. For $p > 1$, the inequality can go either way depending on the signs of $x$ and $y$.

*Proof.* For positive $u, v \in \mathbb{R}$ and $q \geq 1$, we have

$$
(u + v)^q = u(u + v)^{q - 1} + v(u + v)^{q - 1} > u^q + v^q.
$$

Pick some $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ and $0 < p < 1$. Let $u = |x|^p$, $v = |y|^p$, and $q = 1 / p$. Then

$$
|x|^p + |y|^p = u + v > (u^q + v^q)^\frac{1}{q} = (|x| + |y|)^p \geq |x + y|^p.
$$

This gives us the desired inequality $|x|^p + |y|^p > |x + y|^p$.